# neural network doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, neural-network, encog

I'm using  ([ENCOG library](https://s3.amazonaws.com/heatonresearch-books/free/encog-3_3-quickstart.pdf)) to create and train neural network. It must find real fault vector(it has 12 numbers - like vector = signature of fault) from modeling dictionary (it has 70 faults, identifying on 12 frequencies).

In NN i have input(12 neuron = len of one input fault vector), hidden (14 neuron = 2* output neurons) and output(7 neuron - to recognise by '0\1' 70 faults) layers.

This is it code (on C#) with NN:

```
public static double[][] XORInput =
        {
            new double[] { 1, 1, 1, 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2 },
            new double[] { 5, 5, 5, 5,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7 }, 
            new double[] { 6, 6,6,6,6,6,5,5,5,1,2,3 }, 
            new double[] { 3, 3, 3, 3,3,3,3,3,2,2,1,1 } ,
            new double[] { 1, 1, 2, 2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3 },
            new double[] { 1, 4, 2, 7,2,5,6,7,8,8,8,8 },
            new double[] { 2, 3, 3, 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2 },
            new double[] { 7,7, 7, 7,7,8,8,8,7,7,7,7 },
            new double[] { 6, 7, 7, 8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,6 },
            new double[] { 3, 3, 3, 4 ,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3 },
            new double[] { 1, 1, 1, 1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2 },
            new double[] { 5, 5, 5, 5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,7 },
            new double[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,1 },
            new double[] { 1, 1, 1, 1,1,1,1,1,1,2,4,1 },    
            new double[] { 1, 1, 1, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 },
            new double[]  { 5, 5, 5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5 },
            new double[] {7, 8, 8, 8,8,7,6,4,1,2,2,2 },            
            new double[] { 2, 3, 3, 3,3,4,4,4,4,3,3,3 },
            new double[] { 8, 8,8, 8,8,5,6,7,8,8,8,8 },
            new double[] { 5, 5, 5, 5,5,6,8,6,1,1,1,1 },
            new double[] { 1, 1, 1, 1,1,1,1,4,4,6,3,5 },
            new double[] { 2, 2, 2, 2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3 },
           new double[]  { 6, 6, 6, 6,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8 }, 
new double[] { 1, 16, 2, 6,71,72,73,27,74,81,81,58 },
new double[] { 2, 36, 3, 67,87,7,17,27,37,2,1,1 },
new double[] { 3, 46, 4, 8,4,5,6,7,22,8,18,2 },
new double[] { 4, 56, 12, 9,1,2,4,12,4,44,1,8 },
new double[] { 5, 66, 5, 6,17,4,5,11,5,7,8,9 },
new double[] { 6, 86, 6, 6, 10,2,5,8,1,3,5,1 },
new double[] { 66, 16, 14, 11,1,1,1,2,1,4,1,6 },
new double[] { 67, 6,11 , 16,2,2,2,7,21,2,1,9 },
new double[] { 7, 6, 10, 62,12,3,4,54,1,1,3,3 },
new double[] { 8, 16,9, 6,17,7,1,2,7,5,1,4 },
new double[] { 9, 26,11, 6,73,6,2,3,4,5,5,2 },
new double[] { 61, 21, 85, 61,5,2,5,1,6,3,4,5 }, 
new double[]             { 31, 1, 11, 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2 },
            new double[] { 15, 5, 15, 5,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7 }, 
            new double[] { 36, 6,16,6,6,6,5,5,5,1,2,3 }, 
            new double[] { 53, 3, 13, 3,3,3,3,3,2,2,1,1 } ,
            new double[] { 71, 1, 22, 2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3 },
            new double[] { 81, 4, 21, 7,2,5,6,7,8,8,8,8 },
            new double[] { 12, 3, 13, 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2 },
            new double[] { 97,7, 71, 7,7,8,8,8,7,7,7,7 },
            new double[] { 5, 7, 17, 8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,6 },
            new double[] { 13, 3, 13, 4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3 },
new double[]             { 11, 1, 11, 1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2 },
            new double[] { 55, 5, 51, 5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,7 },
            new double[] { 16,2,19,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,1 },
            new double[] { 17, 1, 11, 1,1,1,1,1,1,2,4,1 },
            new double[] { 19, 1, 21, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 },
            new double[] { 25, 5, 25,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5 },           
                        new double[] {27, 8, 28, 8,8,7,6,4,1,2,2,2 },
            new double[] { 22, 3, 23, 3,3,3,3,3,3,2,1,7 },
            new double[] { 32, 3, 27, 3,3,4,4,4,4,3,3,3 },
            new double[] { 18, 8,2, 8,8,5,6,7,8,8,8,8 },
            new double[] { 31, 1, 4, 1,1,1,1,4,4,6,3,5 },
            new double[] { 23, 2, 6, 2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3 },
            new double[] { 36, 6, 16, 6,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8 },
new double[] { 31, 16, 5, 6,71,72,73,27,74,81,81,58 },
new double[] { 12, 36, 14, 67,87,7,17,27,37,2,1,1 },
new double[] { 31, 46, 41, 8,4,5,6,7,22,8,18,2 },
new double[] { 14, 56, 1, 9,1,2,4,12,4,44,1,8 },
new double[] { 15, 66, 59, 6,17,4,5,11,5,7,8,9 },
new double[] { 16, 86, 16, 6, 10,2,5,8,1,3,5,1 },
new double[] { 16, 16, 10, 11,1,1,1,2,1,4,1,6 },
new double[] { 17, 6,114, 16,2,2,2,7,21,2,1,9 },
new double[] { 71, 6, 1, 62,12,3,4,54,1,1,3,3 },
new double[] { 18, 16,19, 6,17,7,1,2,7,5,1,4 },
new double[] { 19, 26,1, 6,73,6,2,3,4,5,5,2 },
new double[] { 6, 21, 5, 61,5,2,5,1,6,3,4,5 } //70
            };


        /// <summary>
        /// Array of numbers, which equal to squares of two
        /// </summary>
        static int[] powOfTwo = {2, 4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384,32768,65536 };    


private static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                double[][] XORIdeal = computeOutputVector(XORInput);
                // normalizing input data
                double[][] input = normalizeData(XORInput);

                // create a neural network, without using a factory
                var network = new BasicNetwork();
                network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(null, true, 12));
                network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(), true, 14));
                network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(), false, 7));       
                network.Structure.FinalizeStructure();
                network.Reset();

                // create training data
                IMLDataSet trainingSet = new BasicMLDataSet(input, XORIdeal);
                //IMLDataSet trainingSet = new BasicMLDataSet(XORInput, XORIdeal);

            // train the neural network
            //IMLTrain train = new ResilientPropagation(network, trainingSet);
            //var train = new Backpropagation ( network , trainingSet , 0.3 , 0.7 ) ;
            var train = new Backpropagation(network, trainingSet, 0.2, 0.15); // speed and influence of backpropogation algorithm

            int epoch = 1;
            do
            {
                train.Iteration();
                Console.WriteLine(@"Epoch #" + epoch + @" Error:" + train.Error);
                epoch++;
            } while (train.Error > 0.05 && epoch < 2000);
            train.FinishTraining();

            // test the neural network
            Console.WriteLine(@"Neural Network Results:");

            double[] data = new double[] { 1, 1, 1, 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2 }; //{ 5.1, 5.4, 5.5, 5.5, 5.8, 5.6, 5.6, 6.5, 6.6, 7.1, 7.1, 7.1 };  // 0000001
            double[] realSignature22 = new double[] { 6.21, 4.2, 6.6, 6.6, 6.6, 5.56, 6.5, 7, 7, 6.89, 6.8, 8 }; // 0010110
            double[] realSignature34 = new double[] { 58, 24, 90, 55, 4.5, 1.82, 5.4, 1.1, 6.4, 3.1, 3.4, 5.3 }; // 0100010

            IMLData example1 = new BasicMLData(normilizeRow(data));
            IMLData output1 = network.Compute(example1);
            Console.WriteLine("\nactual : 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 = #0 ");
            findNumber(output1);   

            IMLData example = new BasicMLData(normilizeRow(realSignature34));
            IMLData output = network.Compute(example);
            Console.WriteLine("\nactual : 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 = #34 ");
            findNumber(output);    

            IMLData example2 = new BasicMLData(normilizeRow(realSignature22));
            IMLData output2 = network.Compute(example2);
            Console.WriteLine("\nactual : 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 = #22 ");    
            findNumber(output2);    

            EncogFramework.Instance.Shutdown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns degree of two which cowers number of mistakes in the input vector
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="XORInput"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        static int calcSizeOfOutputVector(double[][] XORInput)
        {
            int size = 0;
            int len = XORInput.GetLength(0);
            foreach (int number in powOfTwo)
            {
                size++;
                if (len <= number) return size;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        static double[][] computeOutputVector(double[][] XORInput)
        {
            double[][] output;
            int sizeOfOut = calcSizeOfOutputVector(XORInput);
            int numOfFaults = XORInput.GetLength(0);
            output = new double[numOfFaults][];
            // convert decimal number into corresponding array from 0 and 1 (equal to decimal number) 
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfFaults; i++)
            {
                output[i] = new double[sizeOfOut];
                convertDecToByteAndSaveInDoubleArray(output[i], i);               
            }
            return output;
        }

        static double[] convertDecToByteAndSaveInDoubleArray(double[] outArray, int number ){
            // convert number into binary representation
            string binaryCode = Convert.ToString(number, 2);
            int size = outArray.GetLength(0);
            // Initially fill with zeros
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) outArray[i] = 0;
            // 
            for (int i = 0; i < binaryCode.Length; i++)
            {
                double d = Double.Parse(binaryCode.Substring(binaryCode.Length - i - 1, 1));
                outArray[size - 1 - i] = d;
            }
            return outArray;
        }      

        static void printOutputResults(IMLData output){
            Console.WriteLine("\nFrom NN  ");
            for (int i = 0; i < output.Count; i++ )
                Console.Write(" " + output[i] + " " );
        }

        static int[] findNumber(IMLData output)
        {
            int len = output.Count;
            // Round to 0 and 1 numbers, which is received from NN
            int[] outAr = new int[len];
            for (int i = 0; i < output.Count; i++)
            {
                outAr[i] = (int)Math.Round(output[i]);
            }
            // Display output vectors
            // Bug for number 1 and length 7 in the input vector looks like : 0[0] 0[1] 0[2] 0[3] 0[4] 0[5] 1[6] (in binary system) = 1 (in decimal system)
            Console.WriteLine("\nFrom NN ");
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                Console.Write(" " + outAr[i] + " ");
            // Convert binary vector into decimal
            Console.WriteLine("\nFrom NN (converted number)" + convertBinArrayToDecNumber(outAr));
            return outAr;
        }

        static int convertBinArrayToDecNumber(int[] binaryArray)
        {
            int n = 0;
            int maxIndex = binaryArray.Length - 1;
            for (int i = maxIndex; i >= 0; i--)
                n += (int)Math.Pow(2, maxIndex - i) * binaryArray[i];
            return n;
        }

        static double[][] normalizeData(double[][] data)
        {
            int numOfRows = data.Length;
            int lenOfRow = data[0].GetLength(0);
            double[][] result = new double[numOfRows][];
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++)
                result[i] = normilizeRow(data[i]);
            return result;
        }

        static double[] normilizeRow(double[] row)
        {
            int lenOfRow = row.GetLength(0);
            double[] result = new double[lenOfRow];
            for (int i = 0; i < lenOfRow; i++) result[i] = 0;
            double N = 0;
            foreach (double num in row) N += num * num;           
            if (N != 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < lenOfRow; j++)
                {
                    result[j] = (row[j] / Math.Sqrt(N));
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

I try to edit params of training by backpropogation, but almost everytime i have high train.error level.

But the most problem in this code is results. Each run of code has different (and not correct!!!) results. For ex:

```
actual : 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 = #0    
From NN
 0  0  0  0  0  0  1
From NN (converted number)1    
actual : 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 = #34    
From NN
 0  1  0  0  0  1  0
From NN (converted number)34    
actual : 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 = #22    
From NN
 0  0  0  0  0  1  0
From NN (converted number)2
```

Or another:

```
Neural Network Results:    
actual : 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 = #0    
From NN
 0  0  0  0  1  0  1
From NN (converted number)5    
actual : 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 = #34    
From NN
 0  1  0  0  0  1  0
From NN (converted number)34    
actual : 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 = #22    
From NN
 0  0  0  1  1  1  1
From NN (converted number)15
```

Can anyone tell me:

1) how can I train the network more efficiently

2) why rows like '{ 1, 1, 1, 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2 }' (which are in train data) doesn't correctly recognized by NN ?

//-------------------------------------------------------------------

I Try to normilize data with Encog function. Code:

```
public static void  readCSVFileToNN(){
            int numOfCol = 12;
            // Define the format of the data file.
            // This area will change, depending on the columns and 
            // format of the file that you are trying to model.
            IVersatileDataSource source = new CSVDataSource("c:\\test.txt", false,
                CSVFormat.DecimalPoint);
            var data = new VersatileMLDataSet(source);
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfCol; i++ )
                data.DefineSourceColumn("freq#" +i , i, ColumnType.Nominal);

            // Define the column that we are trying to predict.
            ColumnDefinition outputColumn = data.DefineSourceColumn("faultNumbers", 12,
                ColumnType.Nominal);

            // Analyze the data, determine the min/max/mean/sd of every column.
            data.Analyze();

            // Map the prediction column to the output of the model, and all
            // other columns to the input.
            data.DefineSingleOutputOthersInput(outputColumn);

            // Create feedforward neural network as the model type. MLMethodFactory.TYPE_FEEDFORWARD.
            // You could also other model types, such as:
            // MLMethodFactory.SVM:  Support Vector Machine (SVM)
            // MLMethodFactory.TYPE_RBFNETWORK: RBF Neural Network
            // MLMethodFactor.TYPE_NEAT: NEAT Neural Network
            // MLMethodFactor.TYPE_PNN: Probabilistic Neural Network
            var model = new EncogModel(data);
            model.SelectMethod(data, MLMethodFactory.TypeFeedforward);

            // Send any output to the console.
            model.Report = new ConsoleStatusReportable();

            // Now normalize the data.  Encog will automatically determine the correct normalization
            // type based on the model you chose in the last step.
            data.Normalize();

            // Hold back some data for a final validation.
            // Shuffle the data into a random ordering.
            // Use a seed of 1001 so that we always use the same holdback and will get more consistent results.
            model.HoldBackValidation(0.3, true, 1001);

            // Choose whatever is the default training type for this model.
            model.SelectTrainingType(data);
            // Use a 5-fold cross-validated train.  Return the best method found.
            var bestMethod = (IMLRegression)model.Crossvalidate(2, true);

            // Display the training and validation errors.
            Console.WriteLine(@"Training error: " + model.CalculateError(bestMethod, model.TrainingDataset));
            Console.WriteLine(@"Validation error: " + model.CalculateError(bestMethod, model.ValidationDataset));

            // Display our normalization parameters.
            NormalizationHelper helper = data.NormHelper;
            Console.WriteLine(helper.ToString());

            // Display the final model.
            Console.WriteLine(@"Final model: " + bestMethod);
            source.Close();

            // test work of model on the example:
            IMLData input = helper.AllocateInputVector();
            var line = new String[numOfCol];
            var result = new StringBuilder();
            // в качестве примера возьмем сигнатуру [5,5,..,5] под номером 15
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfCol; i++)
                line[i] = 5.ToString();
            String correct = 15.ToString();
            // нормализуем входной вектор
            helper.NormalizeInputVector(line, ((BasicMLData) input).Data, false);
            // производим поиск по НС
            IMLData output = bestMethod.Compute(input);
            // выводим результат
            String faultChosen = helper.DenormalizeOutputVectorToString(output)[0];
                result.Append(line);
                result.Append(" -> predicted: ");
                result.Append(faultChosen);
                result.Append("(correct: ");
                result.Append(correct);
                result.Append(")");

                Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());

        }
```

But results are still bad. I do this function ~10 times and no one of results were not correct

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that each row normalization is independent from other rows. For example the first row will be division of each value at 27, second row will be division of each number at 394. Another source of problems can be   You need to normalize not each row independently, but all rows should be normalized according to some rule. Then you should apply the same normalization rule for your input. I propose you to look at function [normalize](http://heatonresearch-site.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/javadoc/encog-3.3/org/encog/ml/data/versatile/VersatileMLDataSet.html#normalize()) in Encog.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see how you feed into NN normalized data. At which step in code fragment 1 you did it?

Comment: in function `readCSVFileToNN()` that i've add to question post there is a row `data.Normalize();` . I use `readCSVFileToNN()` instead of first posted code fragments and analyze result from it

Comment: Can you please more clearly explain what you did, or present code. For now I can't grasp what you changed